# Formulas for Lists/Tables in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

Trying to add formula to a List/Table programmatically via VBA but not sure about the correct syntaxis.

I need to add formula that looks similar to below:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("B2")="[@Turnover]/SUM([Turnover])"
```

Where "Turnover" is the name of the Column.

I guess there is an issue with escaping characters, but couldn't find any reference or workaraounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close! When giving a range a formula you want to use:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("B2").Formula = "=[@Turnover]/SUM([Turnover])"
```

It just inputs string as a formula to the range.

Comment: That was easy :| Don't believe wasted so much time looking in the wrong direction...